# How to make a django rest api run a python file in my computer

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am making an API for an android app. As soon as the input is given to the API, I need the API to execute a python file for me which is in my computer. I'm thinking of using my computer as a server on trial basis. I hope  you are able to understand my question. Please let me know on how to run a python file from the API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a view that when someone visits the url it will launch another process:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
import subprocess

class ExecutePythonFileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # Execute script
        subprocess.call(['python', 'somescript.py'])

        # Return response
        return HttpResponse("Executed!")
```

Comment: @ShraveenB.S If you find the answer helpful please mark it as correct answer, thanks!